# installing packages - Arch Linux Base System

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, arch-linux

I am trying to learn Arch Linux and have been struggling since a while for installing it.

My problem : I had made a 
boot on partition(sda1) of 1GB.
 
root partition(sda2) of 30GB. 
swap partition(sda3) of 4GB. 
home partition(sda4) of 200GB

After mounting the root partition followed by other partitions, and doing exactly like the procedure explained in the Begineers guide, I got stuck over here.

**pacstrap -i /mnt base base-devel**

I tried installing the developer base(i was just trying to do according to the guide) and later I got an error that the disk got full.

1) when i use **df** command, my **/dev/loop0** shows 100% even after I deleted all the partition and repartitioned them again.

2) I got 123 Packages downloaded twice but it gives me the same error. Please help me formatting the /mnt/loo0 partition. I believe that is the cause.

3) And can anyone explain me that /mnt means which partition is it trying to download in? sda1 with 300MB or sda2 with 30GB. It has to be sda1 i know, but am i going wrong somewhere?

Comment: A 300MB home partition? That is way too little, by at least a factor of 100, if not  1000. Perhaps you might start by installing some more user-friendly Linuxes, like Ubuntu or Mint, and then, when you have acquired some knowledge and some experience, move on to the more difficult OSes like Arch, Kali, ....

Comment: Hey it was a typo. I am really sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You completely misunderstand how partitioning works. `/boot` is only for GRUB and other bootloaders and looks like you didn't read the guide carefully (should read every releated inch if possible). Arch wiki is one of the most detailed wikis on Linux which contains many suggestions, warnings and links for additional info. Always remeber Arch is a "do/configure it yourself" distro and there is not an automated process which mounts your main partition for installation.

Have a look at Beginner's Guide again and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partitioning, and read wiki carefully next time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out myself that the Total Installed Size was 572MB. And my boot partition was just 300MB so naturally it was going to show an error.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Another problem is my Indian Mirrors are too slow, any method by which I can pause the pacstrap command and tweak the mirrorlist and continue the installation?